# OutofBoundsException setpixels

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to fill a rectangle of pixels, but I always get `Arrayindexoutofbounds` at the below line:

```
targetwr.setPixels(i, j, 3, 3, pixel);
```

Here is my code:

```
    WritableRaster sourcewr = source.getRaster();

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    WritableRaster targetwr = bi.getRaster();


    for (int i = 0; i < sourcewr.getWidth() - rate; i += rate) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sourcewr.getHeight() - rate; j += rate) {
            int[] pixel = null;
            pixel = sourcewr.getPixel(i, j, pixel);
            System.out.println(i + " " + j);                

            targetwr.setPixels(i, j, 3, 3, pixel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "if the coordinates are not in bounds, or if dArray is too small to hold the input."  I believe that latter is the case here?

Comment: There is a difference between `getPixel` and `setPixels`. Namely, the `s`. (The one at the end, to be precise). You'll probably need `pixel = sourcewr.getPixels(i,j,3,3,pixel)` to obtain an array with a size that is appropriate for the later call to `setPixels`. Not sure what you are *actually* doing there, though...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: What is the value of `source.getWidth()` & `source.getHeight()` & rate? All depends on it because you have used it in `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward.  The `sourcewr` raster is larger than the `targetwr` raster.  You are iterating over the length and height of the `sourcewr` and never check to see if the coordinates are in-bounds for the `targetwr`.

You can check to see if `i` and `j` are within bounds or ensure that the rasters are the same size before the nested `for` loops.  e.g.,

```
if(i < targetwr.getWidth() && j < targetwr.getHeight()) {
    targetwr.setPixels(i, j, 3, 3, pixel);
}
```

This is obviously also affected by the variable `rate`, whatever that is.  It's not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: rate is the sampling rate. if rate is 3, every third pixel is tracked in the source, then it should fill a rectancle that is 3*3